# Is there a way to split inserted value for example 1234567890 to 12345 and 67890?

Tags: javascript

Is there a function that  splits the the given string into 2 evenly and place half of each to different textboxes?

I have tried var.split and var.slice

```
<script>
    function display() 
    {
    var myStr = document.getElementbyId("reqnum").value;
    var strArray = myStr.split(" ");

    // Display array values on page
    for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
        document.write("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
    }
}
```

the expected should split the no. evenly and would display an error if the numbers are odd.

Comment: why not used substring function.

Comment: Since it looks like the input has no spaces, why are you trying to split on a space? What textboxes are you referring to?

Comment: calculate length of string divide by 2, take floor value as first part, length - floor value as second, make substring based on these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of your input string. If it is odd then display an error.

```html
<input type="text" id="reqnum" >
<input type="button" value="Display" onclick="display()">
<script>
    function display() 
    {
       var myStr = document.getElementById("reqnum").value;
       if( !myStr || myStr.length % 2 == 1){
          document.write("<p>Invalid input</p>");
       }else{
          var a = parseInt(myStr.substring(0, myStr.length/2));
          var b = parseInt(myStr.substring(myStr.length/2, myStr.length));
          document.write("<p>" + a + "</p>");
          document.write("<p>" + b + "</p>");
          document.write("<p> Result after multiplication : " + (a*b) + "</p>");
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Let's say I input 1234 and the result is 12 and 34 how can i multiply them both?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the numbers to string and then you can do the following.

```js
var num = "1234567890"
var num1
var num2
if (num.length % 2 == 0) {
  num1 = num.slice(0, (num.length / 2))
  num2 = num.slice((num.length / 2))
} else {
  console.log("Number contains odd number of digits")
}

console.log("Num1 " + num1 + " and Num2 " + num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `Slice` method, documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

For your slicing in half:

```
let half1, half2;
if( myStr.length % 2 == 0 ){
    half1 = myStr.slice(0, (myStr.length / 2));
    half2 = myStr.slice( (myStr.length / 2), myStr.length );
} else {
 // error code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitToEqual(num){
  num = num.toString()
  return [num.substring(0, num.length / 2), num.substring(num.length / 2, num.length)]
}
console.log(splitToEqual(1234567890))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using *slice* and *length* String methods?

Ie.

```
const string = '1234567890';
const length = string.length;
const res1 = string.slice(0,length/2);
const res2 = string.slice(length/2);
console.log(res1,res2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **substring()** function as

```
var substring=string.substring(strating_index,end_index);
```

index will start from 0

```js
var str="1234567890"
var substr=str.substring(0,str.length/2);
var substr2=str.substring(strlength/2,strlength);
$("#ID1").val(substr);
$('#ID2').val(substr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request, I created the following piece of code :-)

Hope it helps.

```js
var inputBox, warning, fBox, sBox;

function inputBoxChanged(e) {
  var text = e.currentTarget.value;
  if (text.length % 2 != 0) {
    warning.innerText = "Value needs to be even sized";
    fBox.value = "";
    sBox.value = "";
  } else {
    warning.innerText = "";
    var splitPos = text.length / 2;
    fBox.value = text.slice(0, splitPos);
    sBox.value = text.slice(splitPos, text.length);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
  inputBox = document.getElementById("input");
  warning = document.getElementById("warning");
  fBox = document.getElementById("first");
  sBox = document.getElementById("second");
  
  inputBox.addEventListener("change", inputBoxChanged);
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<span id="warning"></span>
<hr/>
<input id="first" type="text" readonly/>
<input id="second" type="text"readonly/>
</body>
</html>
```